# undefined local variable or method `cart_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cart

I have some problem, I using book Agile web development with rails, in Task D:Cart creation, Iam founding the problem,.

Backgound Information.
controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def current_cart
Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
cart = Cart.create
session[:cart_id]= cart_id
cart
end
```

controllers/line_items_controller.rb

```
def create


@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product_id => product.id )
respond_to do |format|
if @line_item.save
format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
              notice: 'Line item was successfully created'}
format.json { render json: @line_item,
              status: :created, location: @line_item }
else
format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
               status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Most likely, this line `session[:cart_id]= cart.cart_id` should be `session[:cart_id]= cart.id`.

Comment: Not `cart_id` as in the edited code, but `cart.id`

Comment: yup, and then I have problem again, please help me, 'uninitialized constant CartsController'

Comment: It's a different problem. Looks like you don't have a controller defined for carts. I suggest you drop the book, and work your way slowly through [Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) to understand the basics of various Ruby on Rails concepts. The book is available for free online, is kept up to date with the best practices, and covers everything that a newcomer needs to know while working with Rails.

Comment: I have completed Michael Hartl's book, :D